# Implementing TokenManager in JavaCC

Tags: compiler-construction, javacc

I want to use the parser only and feed it tokens by implementing TokenManager and using USER_TOKEN_MANAGER=true.

Is there a trick to implementing the class, given that the interface doesn't exist until the parser generator has been run?

I can make my own copy of TokenManager interface and implement it. Then delete the generated TokenManager. But... it seems weird.

Answer (score 1):

Just run JavaCC with the option set to true and it will generate the TokenManager interface.  Then create a new class that implements the interface.  Your class should also implement the ...Constants interface, so you have access to the names of the token kinds.

(Perhaps I am missing the point of the question. If so, please clarify.)